# accepting multiple strings as input in c++

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error when i try to enter the second query as input by pressing 'y' when asked for "Do you want to enter more queries? Enter (y/n)" in my code:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)

My code is:

```
#define SIZE 100

#include "SQLParser.cpp"



using namespace std;



int main() {



    string s[SIZE];

    SQLParser parser;
    char in;
    int i=0;

    cout<<"Enter the input queries:";

    do
    {
    //try
    //{
        std::getline(std::cin,s[i],'\n');
    //cin.ignore(100000, '\n');

    //cout<<" "<<s[i]<<"\n";

    parser[i].sql=s[i];

    parser[i].ProcessSQL();

    cout<<"Do you want to enter more queries? Press (y/n):";

    cin>>in;

    cin.ignore(100000, '\n');

    i++;

    //}
    /*catch (std::exception const &exc)
    {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught " << exc.what() << "\n";
    }*/

    }while(in!='n');

    /*string s("CREATE TABLE tab(aa int,bb string, cc string)");

    string s1("CREATE TABLE xyz(name string,gender char,age int,address string)");
    parser.sql=s;

    //parser1.sql=s1;
    string s2("INSERT INTO tab(name,author,date) VALUES ('aa','bb','cc')");

    //parser.sql = s2;

    parser.ProcessSQL();
    parser.sql = s1;
    parser.ProcessSQL();

    */

    return 1;
}
```

Please help what is the issue with my code.

Comment: What is `s`? Can you include more code, and preferably remove cruft from your debugging?

Comment: From eroor message, I understand that s is a vector of strings, isnt' it ?  Then I guess that you didn't add enough elements.

Comment: int main() {

 

 string s[SIZE];

 SQLParser parser;

 char in;

 int i=0;

 cout<<"Enter the input queries:";

 do

 {

 //try

 //{

  std::getline(std::cin,s[i],'\n');
  //cout<<" "<<s[i]<<"\n";

  parser.sql=s[i];

  parser.ProcessSQL();

  cout<<"Do you want to enter more queries? Press (y/n):";

  cin>>in;

  i++;

 //}

 /*catch (std::exception const &exc)

     {

         std::cerr << "Exception caught " << exc.what() << "\n";

     }*/

 }while(in!='n');

 return 1;

}

Comment: SIZE is #defined to 100

Comment: Don't paste code in comments.  Please edit your question and post the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is residual newline in the input stream.
When you are prompted to continue, you press ``` Y``[ENTER] ```.
Your input stream looks like:

```
+---+------+  
| Y | '\n' |  
+---+------+
```

You perform `cin >> in;` which extracts the `Y` from the stream.  Your stream now looks like:

```
+------+  
| '\n' |  
+------+
```

Going to the top of the loop, your program executes `getline`, which reads until it finds a `\n`.  Since the input stream has one (see above), the `getline` returns with an empty string.

This error can be detected by checking the string after `getline` to verify it is not of length zero. *"Writing programs is easy. Writing robust programs that work correctly is more difficult." -- Thomas Matthews*

**Solution:**
The solution is to use `cin.ignore(100000, '\n')` after you read the input from the continuation prompt.  This will extract the `\n` from the stream so your input stream is *"flushed"* and ready for new input *as you expect*.

Comment: Thomas, I have changed the code as you said. But when i try to create array of objects and try to run the above code. It is again throwing me the same error. The value is stored in s[i] but i do not understand where the problem exactly is. Can you please see this?

Comment: Two suggestions:  1) Use a debugger; 2) Use `std::vector` not arrays.  Try these.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, **then spend time and learn to use the debugger**.